# Updating UI objects in windows forms

Tags: c#, winforms

Pre .net I was using MFC, ON_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI, and the CCmdUI class to update the state of my windows UI.
From the older MFC/Win32 reference:

> Typically, menu items and toolbar buttons have more than one state. For
> example, a menu item is grayed
> (dimmed) if it is unavailable in the
> present context. Menu items can also
> be checked or unchecked. A toolbar
> button can also be disabled if
> unavailable, or it can be checked.
>
> Who updates the state of these items
> as program conditions change?
> Logically, if a menu item generates a
> command that is handled by, say, a
> document, it makes sense to have the
> document update the menu item. The
> document probably contains the
> information on which the update is
> based.
>
> If a command has multiple
> user-interface objects (perhaps a menu
> item and a toolbar button), both are
> routed to the same handler function.
> This encapsulates your user-interface
> update code for all of the equivalent
> user-interface objects in a single
> place.
>
> The framework provides a convenient
> interface for automatically updating
> user-interface objects. You can choose
> to do the updating in some other way,
> but the interface provided is
> efficient and easy to use.

What is the guidance for .net Windows Forms? I am using an Application.Idle handler in the main form but am not sure this is the best way to do this. About the time I put all my UI updates in the Idle event handler my app started to show some performance problems, and I don't have the metrics to track this down yet. Not sure if it's related.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do again?  Are you trying to disable controls on WinForms applications?

Comment: Disable/enable toolbar buttons, menu items, etc. Check/uncheck state of check buttons on toolbar, menu items that show a check state. That sort of thing. Very routine stuff.

Comment: Yes, Application.Idle.  How you could have a perf problem when the app is idle is mysterious.

Answer (score 1):

I've found it easiest to have the menu item event handler spawn a background thread that disables the menu item, does the work, and then re-enables the menu item. That way, the UI is available to handle other UI requests, and I don't need to poll for when the operation is complete.

I usually include logic that prevents more than one operation that uses the same resources to happen simultaneously. This means creating a function to disable/enable all similar resources at once. e.g. I might only allow 1 file operation to happen at a time, so I would create a function to disable/enable all the menu items associated with file operations and call it from every one of those menu items.

Answer (score 1):

Just change their property, e.g.

```
obj.Enabled = true;
```

or

```
obj.Enabled = false;
```

The property of that object will automatically call `.Invalidate()` or `.Refresh()` for you, so the control should be repainted automatically.

If you want to do a BIG task which would block the UI for multiple seconds, it's worth using [Threads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.aspx) + [Delegates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.delegate.aspx).

Comment: That's what I do now in the Application.Idle handler in the main form. I am trying to find out how when and where others are doing this. I can't use data binding since devexpress menus and toolbars I use don't offer data binding for this.

Comment: well this would mean to blow up the Application.Idle-handler for larger forms. you really shouldn't do this. just do it when neccessary. eg: add an onclick-event to a button. in your handler, disable another control. don't put this in application.idle.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, in the standard .NET System.Windows.Forms world, this functionality is not available out the box.
This problem can be answered in a few ways. The links below are useful resources:

•[OnUpdate equivalent](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/464ea3aa-007f-40e0-9dde-b9a7adbac9a4/onupdate-equivalent?forum=csharpgeneral)

•[ActionLists for Windows forms](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1916/ActionLists-for-Windows-Forms)

•[Command UI Updating Windows Forms in C#](https://web.archive.org/web/20200131055756/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/willemf/archive/2007/06/05/113005.aspx)

Comment: I saw some of these links before and I have my own implementation of the command pattern. All these guys are doing is using the Application.Idle event for the updating. I guess that all there is to it. The old C++ MFC way was pretty cool however.