# Setting menu item state on a MenuStrip

Tags: c#, winforms, menustrip

In Visual C++ MFC there is an inbuilt mechanism for setting the menu item states. I am trying to do the same with C# and a WindowsForm object.

I found this which is not quite the same:

[Grey out menustrip items when certain forms are open/active/focused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23435074/grey-out-menustrip-items-when-certain-forms-are-open-active-focused)

Here is my menu structure:

[image: Sub menu]

So, I decided to try this:

```
private void viewToolStripMenuView_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    zoomExtentsToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = viewCtrl != null;
}
```

It kind of works. But I am a bit picky. I can see the menu displayed with the item enabled and **then** I see it change to disabled.

What is the right way to set the menu item states **before** the menu is displayed? I know this sounds like a simple issue but I can't find the equivalent methodology to **ON_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI**.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Updating UI objects in windows forms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2405592/updating-ui-objects-in-windows-forms)

Comment: @JohnnyMopp That is an interesting question and it does look the same, thank you. But I don't see the need to do a background thread for updating the UI. I should be able to just set it as Enabled etc. But it is picking the right event handler to do it in. Clearly, doing it in the View menu item click event handler is too late.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using the wrong event handler!

```
private void viewToolStripMenuView_DropDownOpening(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    zoomExtentsToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = viewCtrl != null;
}
```

Comment: Indeed, this is sufficient. There is no reason for a background thread. This code is *much* faster than the smallest amount of lag that is perceptible by a human user. It is morally equivalent to handling the WM_INITMENUPOPUP message with real menus (rather than the fake, user-drawn .NET ones).